# Style text database output

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a database with an input of text (as opposed to string) and I am outputting it in a

tag in html. Unfortunately it outputs a block of text and I don't know how to style it at all, or even create a line break.

DB Field is:

```
t.string :content
```

In my text_area input, the text is a simple lore ipsum.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec risus ligula. Nulla quis bibendum justo. Sed nec tempus nisi. Curabitur in justo in mi ornare dictum sed et mi. Praesent sodales arcu nec ligula accumsan et gravida nulla gravida. Nullam in diam odio, a malesuada eros. Nunc et magna quis odio fermentum porta in et magna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis interdum, lacus malesuada mollis ullamcorper, tellus turpis placerat magna, non gravida tortor magna vel turpis. Nunc eu nunc nec nisi scelerisque mollis at cursus lectus. Quisque varius condimentum neque elementum rutrum. Cras porta, felis vitae porta cursus, nisl turpis tincidunt turpis, eu molestie ipsum ligula sit amet lectus. Sed aliquam lobortis nunc, at lobortis magna tristique vel. Donec faucibus ipsum non elit rhoncus posuere.
```

Html is simply

```
<p><%= @building.content %></p>
```

The input HTML is

```
<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
```

I have no CSS styling on it yet.

Comment: post your HTML and CSS code

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you wanting to format the text? If you just want to change the font, justification, size, or emphasis then you can just use CSS. If you're wanting to turn text into multiple paragraphs I'd probably just save it that way to the database. Though you would want to html encode the text first and then decode before outputting it to the page. HTH

Comment: How do I save it into the database with multiple paragraphs? I'll update the code to show the input field.

Comment: Okay, just to make sure I fully understand the problem. You have an textarea  input on an html page that saves the text to the database and  will later be retrieved from said db and displayed on a page. I would think you would just add any html markup to your text in the textarea before saving it to the DB. Again, though whatever you are using to process the text and save it to the DB will need to be encoded. [Check out this link about sanitizing in RoR](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this and fix your width according to your requirement.

```
<p style="word-wrap: break-word;"><%= @building.content %></p>
```